# Uninstall MacPorts

Tags: homebrew, macports

I want to switch to Homebrew instead of MacPorts because Homebrew told me to (http://cl.ly/image/1b0M0q2x1C3K) and it seems better.
I'm a bit weary about how to uninstall MacPorts since it's installed trough Terminal and not trough .app as a regular OS X program.

How do I uninstall?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

will uninstall all ports.

Then read the guide for cleaning up the leftover bits.

https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

Comment: I got this error `Error: No ports matched the given expression` when used `sudo port -fp uninstall installed`. What might be the possible reason?

Comment: @ptamzz Did you install any port packages?  This doesn't remove macports, it removes all of the packages installed *by* macports.  See the guide link in the answer to uninstall macports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brew along with macports without any issues as brew installs the packages under a different directory.

I have been using both of these package managers without any problems.

Macports and Brew are better in their own way, you never know when you might want to use macports, it is going to get better and faster.

I tend to use both depending on what I want to install and do further.

If you still insist on uninstalling MacPorts, you can follow the steps as mentioned by Kirk Roybal.

Comment: Sometimes homebrew throws up this error: `Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew.` So no, I don't think they're compatible

Comment: It is just a warning message though. There might be a problem when you have packages installed by different package managers. But as I said it depends which package you want to install / is installed. There are some packages available in Homebrew that are not yet available in MacPorts. In that case you can use them both as both are using different prefix to install the packages (as long as you are careful).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post.
But for clarity:  brew installs to /usr/local.  macports installs to /opt/local. When you have duplicates (binaries, objects, libraries) and/or version difference (i.e. duplicates that have the same name but are different versions), then you can have issues if you do not manage it. Manage it through your command search rules (PATH in bash,csh for example) and your library search rules if applicable. If you have a collision that can't be resolved this way or you don't want to deal with it, then you have to pick one - i.e. delete the one you don't want and replace it with a link to the one to keep. I've used both MacPorts and Brew for a long time successfully.